# Why does 卻 mean both "decline; retreat" and "but, yet, still' while"?

Tags: etymology

| 詞類 | 英文意義 |
| --- | --- |
| adv. | **but, yet, still, however; while** |
| v. | `reject, decline, withdraw; retreat, step back` |

http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8D%BB writes that 卻's semantic component is [卩](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8D%A9). 卩 is "a person assuming a kneeling posture (arch.)".

But how is "kneeling" related to `"reject, decline, withdraw; retreat, step back"`? If I was a soldier retreating from a [human wave attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_wave_attack) or calvary charge, then I definitely wouldn't be "kneeling"! I'd be running and facing AWAY from the enemy!  This is the first puzzle.

The second puzzle is knottier. Where does the meaning of **"but, yet, still, however; while**" stem from? How is **"but, yet, still, however; while"** related to kneeling???  Notice the different 詞類!

Comment: There are 幾種詞類--> http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/cgi-bin/agrep-lindict?query=%ABo&category=wholerecord

Comment: radical lookup:  https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Words such as 卻 have an ancient origin, providing three thousand or more years for meanings to shift and the grammar to change.  On a similar time scale, the English words "deem" and "doom" and "the suffix "-dom" in "wisdom," "boredom," and "kingdom" were closely related in meaning and stemmed from an Indo-European root [*dʰeh₁-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0eh%E2%82%81-) still represented in the verb "to do."

As far as we can trace back, 卻 seems to have originally meant "to repel, to subdue."  The component卩 seems to suggest forcing an enemy to kneel and so helped to indicate the semantics.  With a [change in valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)#Changing_valency), the word meant "to be repelled/driven back or to retreat."  From there, the meaning seems to have shifted to "to refuse/reject/decline."  From there, the meaning was extended to "however/yet/but" since one option or statement of facts is "rejected" for a different one.

Answer (score -1):

Just speculation on my part, I have no proof:

Maybe work backwards from but?

The basic meaning of **but** is: "outside of that, outside"

**but** is from Old English **butan**, buton, which basically means "**outside**".

**buiten** is used in Dutch and **buten** is used Plattdeutsch (Low German) today with exactly that meaning: **outside**

jué looks a lot like 谷 gǔ but apparently they are not one and the same.

Even today, people will kneel before a potentate. If the enemy army, in those ancient times, forced your surrender, they may not just slaughter everyone.

Pledge allegiance 卩 jié to the new lord and you may go: go-variant 去 jué.

When you are gone, you are "**buten**" (Ik ga na buten, I'm going outside.) and you are "**still**" alive!

A nice quote about but:

> Som man preiseth his neighebore by a wikked entente, foralwey he
> maketh a 'but' at the laste ende, that is digne of moore blame than
> worth is al the preisynge. [Chaucer, "Parson's Tale"]

Comment: thank you. upvoted you. You could improve your answer, if you cited as much of your answer as possible? I found your Chaucer quotation on Etymonline, which suggests you used Etymonline too?

Answer (score -1):

| 部首 | 意義 |
| --- | --- |
| 卩 | 關節之「節」的初文 |

[image: 「節」的初文]

therefore,  it is not about the kneeling posture

English explanation:  [the meaning is 'restrain'](http://zhongwen.com/d/171/x111.htm)

從「卩」，「口」聲，表示使之退

Comment: https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&rad=26